# How to search multiple values in same column in MySQL JOIN?

Tags: mysql

I have tried my best to explain my problem. Please go through my question carefully to understand what I want to achieve.

I am trying to search multiple values in same column in MySQL. I have following 4 tables employed in this operations which are:

**contacts:**

[image]

**data_values:**

[image]

**data_fields:**

[image]

**data_cats_options:**

[image]

On my website front-end, the filters (form elements to search for required data) look as:

[image]

[image]

**Single drop-down (country) search:**

To fetch all contacts with name "Sachin" whose "Country" is "India", I use following query:

```
SELECT `c`.* 
FROM `contacts` AS `c` JOIN `data_values` AS `dv` 
ON `c`.`contact_id` = `dv`.`contact_id` 
JOIN `data_fields` AS `df` ON 
`dv`.`field_id` = `df`.`field_id` 
JOIN `data_cats_options` AS `dco` ON 
`dv`.`field_val` = `dco`.`val_id`  
WHERE `c`.`contact_name` = "Sachin" AND `dv`.`field_id` = 153 AND `dco`.`val_id` = 224
```

Similarly, we can do for all "Sachin" who are accountant for "Job" dropdown.

**PROBLEM**

I really can't figure out how to search for multiple data e.g. How to fetch all contacts with "Sachin" whose "Country" is "India" AND "Job" is "Accountant". The following SQL gives me no result though the data exists in the database:

```
SELECT `c`.* 
FROM `contacts` AS `c` JOIN `data_values` AS `dv` 
ON `c`.`contact_id` = `dv`.`contact_id` 
JOIN `data_fields` AS `df` ON 
`dv`.`field_id` = `df`.`field_id` 
JOIN `data_cats_options` AS `dco` ON 
`dv`.`field_val` = `dco`.`val_id`  
WHERE `c`.`contact_name` = "Sachin" AND `dv`.`field_id` = 153 AND `dco`.`val_id` = 224 
AND `dv`.`field_id` = 154 AND `dco`.`val_id` = 227
```

My main concern is all about this particular segment of above query:

```
AND `dv`.`field_id` = 153 AND `dco`.`val_id` = 224 
AND `dv`.`field_id` = 154 AND `dco`.`val_id` = 227
```

So how can we search the multiple data in same columns in this JOIN?

I really want to fetch all those records which fulfills both dropdown options.

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to join to data fields twice once for country and once for job.  Or you have to use an or clause and a having count distinct field_ID =2 since your searching for two values)

Comment: Using an `OR` as suggested by previous comment (which no longer exist now) gives me "Sachin" from India even he is not an "Accountant" which is wrong. ` WHERE `c`.`contact_name` = "Sachin" AND ((`dv`.`field_id` = 153 AND `dco`.`val_id` = 224) OR (`dv`.`field_id` = 154 AND `dco`.`val_id` = 227))`

Comment: "Sachin" must return when country is India and job is accountant. If we select some other job then no result should come because we are combining country and job together

Comment: @xQbert you said - `You need to join to data fields twice once for country and once for job.` how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bad design because we have to add additional joins.

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM contacts AS c 
JOIN data_values AS dv 
  ON c.contact_id = dv.contact_id 
JOIN data_fields AS df 
  ON dv.field_id = df.field_id 
JOIN data_cats_options AS dco 
  ON dv.field_val = dco.val_id 
JOIN data_values AS dv2 
  ON c.contact_id = dv2.contact_id 
JOIN data_fields AS df2 
  ON dv2.field_id = df2.field_id 
JOIN data_cats_options AS dco2 
  ON dv2.field_val = dco2.val_id 
WHERE c.contact_name = "Sachin" 
  AND dv.field_id = 153 AND dco.val_id = 224 
  AND dv2.field_id = 154 AND dco2.val_id = 227
```

I'm still considering other options but need need to do something else for a bit.

Perhaps...  the 2 would be dynamically set based on the number of field_ID's being searched on ; which you know since you have the field_IDs...

```
SELECT c.contact_ID, C.Contact_name
FROM contacts AS c 
JOIN data_values AS dv 
  ON c.contact_id = dv.contact_id 
JOIN data_fields AS df 
  ON dv.field_id = df.field_id 
JOIN data_cats_options AS dco 
  ON dv.field_val = dco.val_id 
WHERE c.contact_name = "Sachin" 
  AND (dv.field_id = 153 AND dco.val_id = 224 
  OR dv.field_id = 154 AND dco.val_id = 227)
GROUP BY c.contact_ID, C.Contact_name
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

Why this works?  Because we know that if both matches occur, we will get 2 records per contact_ID if both don't exist we would only get 1 record. thus the having lets us limit the desired way.

Or we could use 
HAVING COUNT(*) = (Select count(*) from data_Fields where field_ID in ('153','154'))

Comment: OMG! so many JOINs! Don't we other way to sort out it? Is my database design faulty?

Comment: But what when we have more than 2 filters? We will need to join more and more which makes query absolutely crap and complex.

Comment: O I agree just haven't had time to look more into it yet.

Comment: oh i think in your latest solution `HAVING count(*) = 2` needs to be removed because if there are more than one person with name "sachin" then your query will show only one result.

Comment: also if we select country india and job other than accountant, your query still shows sachin in result which is wrong because sachin from india is an accountant. this is because of `or`. But `and` does not bring the result even the search fulfills the criteria.